# Using gulp in Play Framework application which has subprojects(modules) in it

Tags: java, playframework

I have a play application with modules in it. I have a **folder** called **ui/** inside **root project folder** in which I have all the html,javascript,stylesheets(**UI related files**).

When I try run the application it **searches** for **ui/ folder inside the modules sub projects** as well and throws error. Anyone tried like this before in Play application.

I am trying to have different modules(sub projects) for different functionalities. Is there any better idea to **categorize functionalities** into modules in play 2 framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML, JS and CSS should be under the public folder and not the root project folder.